# Photos "self deleted" off Galaxy 3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, photos, file-transfer

As I was trying to transfer photos from my galaxy 3 to my mac, one of my albums containing over 1500 pictures deleted itself.  I watched the album count slowly decrease.  Why did it do this and how do I get the pictures back?  The album isn't even in my gallery anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Recover images using [Data Recovery for Mac](http://www.iskysoft.com/data-recovery-mac/)

Step 1: Connect SD Card to Mac and Open Data Recovery for Mac
Connect your SD card to your Mac either with a card reader or without pulling out from your device. And then run iSkysoft Recovery on your Mac from Application folder or any folder you've installed it to. This SD card recovery application supports all popular files systems on SD cards, including FAT16, FAT32, exFAT, NTFS, HFS+, and HFSX.

Step 2: Scan lost SD card files
In the "Lost Data Recovery" window, choose the drive of your Mac OS X system and click "Scan" on top to start scanning removed files from Trash as well as other locations.

Step 3: Preview and recover SD card files
When scanning complete, you will see the window below. On the left is the folder tree, with which you can quickly find lost SD card file if you know the folder name. In the bottom list, click the file to preview and find out whether the file is what you want to recover.

Note : This is paid app there are also also free apps available like [mac photo recovery free](http://www.easeus.com/mac/mac-photo-recovery-free/)